# Как сделать инвентарь для дискорд бота на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я бы хотел бы сделать так чтобы когда человек писал команду find и если ему что нибудь выпало то это добавлялось в его инвентарь.

1. Как сделать инвентарь?
2. Как сделать так чтобы туда добавлялись предметы?

````
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('=help'):
        await message.channel.send('Мои команды: =find')

    if message.content.startswith('=find'):
        a = ['Окей, ты нашел... \nНИЧЕГО!!!', 'Окей, ты нашел... \nпалку!']
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(a))


client.run('мой токен')

#import discord
#from discord.ext import commands
#
#bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
#
#@bot.command()
#async def ping(ctx):
#    await ctx.send('pong')
#
#bot.run('мой токен')```
````

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать json, но для этого нужно сделать авторизацию думаю как сделать её сможешь этот код описывает как можно сделать ту часть с записью данных в файл как-то так :

```
invent_list = []
filename = 'invent.json'
inventari = open(filename, mode='w', encoding='Latin-1')
invent = {
  'user': имя,
  'member_id': member.id,
  'предмет': предмет,
                             
}

invent_list.append(invent)
json.dump(memberreg, inventari , sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Надеюсь, тебе помогло)

Comment: в строке предмет можно задать пустую строку как пустой